# Apex:SelectOption does not show selected value on page reload

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectoption

I am trying to get values for apex select list from a API call.
I can get all the values, show them on the page, do what I need to do etc.
However, when I reload the page, I my dropdown list does not retain the selected value.

VF Page code

```
<apex:page standardController="Signature__c" extensions="DocusignTemplates" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <apex:form style="margin-left:-0.9em">
        <apex:outputLabel >Select Template</apex:outputLabel><br/>
        <apex:selectList size="1" style="margin-left:0px;width:100%" value="{!selectedTemplate}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateSelectedTemplate}"/>
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!filteredTemplates}"/>
        </apex:selectList><p/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller Class

```java
public class DocusignTemplates {
    private Signature__c signatures;
    public String selectedTemplate;
    public DocusignTemplates (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        signatures = (Signature__c)controller.getRecord();
    }
    
    public DocusignRESTUtility dru = new DocuSignRESTUtility();
    public String templatesJSON = dru.getDocusignData(DocuSignRESTUtility.TEMPLATES);
    public DocusignTemplateListBean templateData = (DocusignTemplateListBean) System.JSON.deserialize(templatesJSON, DocusignTemplateListBean.class);
    public List <EnvelopeTemplateBean> envelopeTemplates = templateData.envelopeTemplates;
    
    public List <SelectOption> getFilteredTemplates() {
        List <SelectOption> myTemplates = new List<SelectOption>();
        myTemplates.add(new SelectOption('','--No Template--'));
        for(EnvelopeTemplateBean envelopeTemplate : envelopeTemplates) {
                if(envelopeTemplate.name != '')
                    myTemplates.add(new SelectOption(envelopeTemplate.templateId, envelopeTemplate.name));
        }
        return myTemplates;
    }
    
    public String getSelectedTemplate() {
        return selectedTemplate;
    }
    public void setSelectedTemplate(String templateId) {
        this.selectedTemplate = templateId;
    }
    
    public PageReference updateSelectedTemplate() {
        system.debug('selected template: '+ getSelectedTemplate());
        this.signatures.Selected_Template__c = getSelectedTemplate();
        update this.signatures;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Before reloading page, everything works fine and I can store value in another field

[image: Before reloading page]

After reloading page, selected value is not restored from another field
[image]

How do I retain the value in Dropdown after page reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the design, now I created another object which will get data at regular intervals and created a lookup relation with my custom object.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "relaod page" I'm assuming you mean when the page refreshes due to action method `updateSelectedTemplate` (the return null). Normally, one simply makes the action method void if you are not causing a new Page to be displayed (wizard-style or redirect)

I would suggest you make the selectOptions a lazyload and move the docusign call into the lazyload rather than when the controller is instantiated. This helps avoid the indeterminate ordering of getters

```
public List <SelectOption> filteredTemplates {
    get {
      if (filteredTemplates == null) {
         DocusignRESTUtility dru = new DocuSignRESTUtility();
         String templatesJSON = 
            dru.getDocusignData(DocuSignRESTUtility.TEMPLATES);
         DocusignTemplateListBean templateData = (DocusignTemplateListBean) System.JSON.deserialize(templatesJSON, DocusignTemplateListBean.class);

         filteredTemplates = new List<SelectOption>();
         filteredTemplates.add(new SelectOption('','--No Template--'));
         for(EnvelopeTemplateBean envelopeTemplate : envelopeTemplates) {
            if(envelopeTemplate.name != '')
                filteredTemplates.add(new SelectOption(envelopeTemplate.templateId, envelopeTemplate.name));
       }
       return filteredTemplates;
    } private set;
}
```

I would also make for convention (only variables that the VF page references directly should be public:

```
private String selectedTemplate;
```

and for clarity and consistency

```
public String getSelectedTemplate() {
    return this.selectedTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for some great tips to improve code quality
When I say reload page, I mean either I press F5 or user leaves the page and comes back at later time.

Comment: well, F5 wipes out the controller memory and viewstate so you'll need to persist the selected item outside of the controller to be refetched later -- VF cookies, hierarchical custom settings, or User object